# Determine if command line program is installed C++

Tags: c++, command-line, system

I am trying to find out if a command line program is installed, so that it can be used later.

So far what I have tried is:

```
int whichReturn = system("command -v THE_CL_PROGRAM >/dev/null && { exit 50; }|| { exit 60; }");
if (whichReturn == 12800) { //system 'apparently' returns the return value *256 (50*256 = 12800)

    //...

}
```

However it seems that it always returns 60 and so fails.

Is there an easier way to do this? Or can someone point out where my mistake is please?

Thanks

Comment: Parse the output from `which`?

Comment: [man which](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which) You can even just use the return code - 0 means found, 1 means not found (somewhere in the path - if it's not in the PATH, you're out of luck with such simple commands, you'd have to `find` the command manually...)

Comment: @nyarlathotep I tried that as well, using the `-s` argument, but this didn't work either.. It returns '256' for a command which when in terminal I enter `which THE_PROGRAM` returns a path, so it does find it

Comment: then you're probably running your program under a different user or in a different environment than your terminal. for me, running which from c++ returns 256 for commands not found and 0 for programs in the path

Comment: and by the way what `-s` argument? my version of which (ubuntu 13.10) doesn't have that, which OS are you on?

Comment: @nyarlathotep ok, I'll try to create a release version and test it again, it could be the fact it's in debug mode. I'm on OS X, in that case, I'll remove the `-s`, will it still return the same way?

Comment: ah OS X! Ok that might be quite different there ;) I have no idea what "-s" would do - what does `man which` say about it?

Comment: @nyarlathotep Taken from the man page:
`-s      No output, just return 0 if any of the executables are found, or 1 if none are found.`

Comment: Incidentally, which is not mandated by POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete program using `which`:

isthere.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        std::ostringstream cmd;
        cmd << "which " << argv[1] << " >/dev/null 2>&1";
        bool isInstalled = (system(cmd.str().c_str()) == 0);
        std::cout << argv[1] << " is "<< ((isInstalled)?"":"NOT ") << "installed! << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./isthere ls
ls is installed!
$ ./isthere grep
grep is installed!
$ ./isthere foo
foo is NOT installed!
```

Comment: `isthere foo 
which: no foo in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.6.3:/usr/games/bin:/home/nm/bin)
1`

Comment: which linux version do you use? in ubuntu 13.10, there is no such output as you state. probably your version of `which` is printing to `stderr`? or what is actually the commmand you're exactly running? `isthere foo which`?

Comment: Gentoo. So much for portability of this solution.

Comment: what about appending `2>&1` at the end? i.e. after `>/dev/null` that should suppress all output from which. have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Probably won't work for users of csh and friends (well, they do deserve a light beating if you ask me).

Comment: Thank you, the issue was that it was a debug build, so I assume Xcode used a special user and not mine!